# Javascript animation override

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, shieldui

I have a page where I am displaying multiple charts on a ASP.NET page at any one time (between 1 and 12 charts at a time) however when wanting to print the page we need to disable all the animation globally on this page.

**Question:**
Is there a JavaScript (or any other method) override to disable animation on every *chart* on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the animation on each individual chart, rather than all of them. 
This is achieved via the EnableAnimation property and is demonstrated in the following example:

https://demos.shieldui.com/aspnet/line-chart/forex-data

I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work as we use a main class for all our charts when they are being put on the page. What I need is a "override" that can be used on the page load to stop animation as using the inbuilt property is not an option.

Comment: I see. 
Well, in this case you can contact ShieldUI support to make sure that I am not leaving something our.